# Getting Unsatisfied Link error while making a JNI call

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I get the Unsatisfied link error while calling the JNI method.Below are my logs

Logs

```
 new exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: demo.JNIWrapper.packet_mining_start(Ljava/lang/String;)I] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: demo.JNIWrapper.packet_mining_start(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at demo.JNIWrapper.packet_mining_start(Native Method)
    at demo.RESTController.getPcap(RESTController.java:97)
```

Below is my JNI Code

```
public class JNIWrapper {

    static{


        System.load("/home/XXX/XXX/Library/newJNI/libJNIDemo.so");


    }



    //Get Path in output param and status
    public native int  packet_mining_start(String fileName);
}
```

Now This method is called from a file Main.java and while creating the Object for this class (JNIWrapper jni=new JNIWrapper()) during which  the System.load call is made **I dont receive any error .**

Now when I call the method packet_mining_start in the JNI I get the error .

My .h file **method**  is (Note not created from the Java class file )

```
uint32_t pax_packet_mining_start(uint8_t* mining_query_file_name);
```

This method does not contain JNIExport and JNICall variables or types in it .So if a method which does not contain JNIExport and calling that method will give UnsatisfiedLink error ?

Is it mandatory to have JNICall and JNIExport in the native method ?

How can i integrate this with my normal c file ?

Comment: `My .h file method is (Note not created from the Java class file )`  So you didn't use `javah.exe` to create the C headers?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i didnt use javah to create the header file (Basically experimenting how can I call a native method without creating header file using javah)

Comment: The method described by the stack trace, `demo.JNIWrapper.packet_mining_start(Ljava/lang/String;)I`, does not match the one declared in the Java code you presented.  They differ in argument number and type.  Either you are leaving out crucial details or your classes are in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it mandatory to have JNICall and JNIExport in the native method ?as I suspect that the JNI method does not contain JNIExport and JNICall it may be issue ,My JNI method is 
uint32_t pax_packet_mining_start(uint8_t* mining_query_file_name);

Comment: You should use the function prototype generated for you by `javah` also in the function implementation.  In any event, the C function signature you describe does not match *either* Java signature -- neither the one in your Java code or the one given in your stack trace.  At minimum, the argument and return types are incorrect.  If your real Java code overloads native methods with that name, then the C function *name* is incorrect, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes sorry the java code pasted was old code..corrected it with the present code .The name of function is not same.But the parameter and return type I guess they are the same in the java code and header file

Comment: With your edit, the Java code is consistent with the method signature in the stack trace.  The C function signature you give is still *incorrect* for that Java signature, however.  Again, use the exact function declaration that `javah` generates for the header.

Comment: Also, you would ordinarily give `System.loadLibrary()` a library name without the ".so" extension or the path.  In place of the path, you might set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory wherein the library may be found (before launching the program).  Perhaps Java is smart enough to understand the form you have given, however.

Comment: /home/XXX… has nothing to do with Android

Answer (score 2):

JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are defined according to the platform you're on. If you're using a windows system, JNIEXPORT will be mandatory in a DLL since DLL's contain information about what functions are exported, and the function will not be visible outside your DLL (and thus you cannot load it). On Linux systems, symbols are exported anyways, so you don't need to explicitly declare this on them.

JNICALL is a calling convention, which is stdcall on windows, and cdecl everywhere else. If your calling convention is incorrect, you will probably corrupt the stack causing a segmentation fault, but this doesn't seem to be the problem at the time.

There's another problem, you seem to be taking an uint8_t* as argument, whereas you pass a java String object to the method. In java, String is an object type and it isn't automatically converted to a C style const char*.

You'll have to have another function between these two functions that accepts the Java arguments, has the correct calling convention and is exported outside your library, then converts the Java String object to an uint8_t* and calls your original function. This way you'll resolve this error (and possibly more errors you'll run into later on).

And since you tagged this question as C++ as well, don't forget to put extern "C" in front of your function so your compiler doesn't mangle the names. Java isn't able to find functions once their names are mangled.

Comment: *On Linux systems, symbols are exported anyways* unless you change default visibility to "hidden"